# how can i use find() in using xpath

Tags: javascript, testing, xpath, automation, cypress

i am trying a drag and drop in an iframe and to do that i need to pass xpath in find since i cant find  a unique element to pass in cy.get()

currently i am trying

```js
cy.xpath('//div[@class="unlayer-editor"]//iframe[@src]')
  .should("be.visible")
  .find('//div[@class = "blopockbder-coent-tols43 col-sm-12"]//div[@aria-describedby="t8ppy-tooltip-9"]')
```

but this isnt working

i am using cypress for automation

Comment: Please add you add your HTML to the question

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert on xpath, but I think `.find()` can't be mixed with an xpath selector.

Two things to try

```js
// chain 2nd xpath in place of .find()

cy.get('div[class="unlayer-editor"] iframe[id="my-iframes-id"]')
  .should("be.visible")
  .xpath('//div[@class = "blopockbder-coent-tols43 col-sm-12"]//div[@aria-describedby="t8ppy-tooltip-9"]')
```

or

```js
// use .within() instead of .find() (roughly equivalent)

cy.get('div[class="unlayer-editor"] iframe[id="my-iframes-id"]')
  .should("be.visible")
  .within(() => {
    cy.xpath('//div[@class = "blopockbder-coent-tols43 col-sm-12"]//div[@aria-describedby="t8ppy-tooltip-9"]')
  })
```

---

**Other things that might need adjusting**

The `iframe` selection generally needs a follow-up command to get it's document body (ref [Working with iframes](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/))

```js
// get the iframe document body any select within it

cy.get('div[class="unlayer-editor"] iframe[id="my-iframes-id"]')
  .its('0.contentDocument.body', { log: false }).should('not.be.empty')
  .within(() => {
    cy.xpath('//div[@class = "blopockbder-coent-tols43 col-sm-12"]//div[@aria-describedby="t8ppy-tooltip-9"]')
  })
```

Some of those classes in the path like `col-sm-12` are purely display-oriented and may be different if you test at different devices. Once the test works, try removing them to make the test more robust.

Comment: $iframe.contents(...).within is not a function  , got this error with withing()

Comment: Difficult to interpret that error. Try changing the iframe selector, see my adjustment -  try to find the id of the iframe. `src` attribute is not a good selector.